# Ubuntu 15.10 gets very slow while copy files, is it safe to change dirty_ratio setting?

Tags: copy

My Ubuntu 15.10 hangs while copying files and at some point even the cursor freezes. It's annoying.

In this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1208993), a saw a work ground, which consists in modifying dirty_ratio settings, this way:

> vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5 vm.dirty_ratio = 10
>
> in /etc/sysctl.conf and running sysctl -p

It works! But is it safe? Could this get my files corrupted or something else? Thanks!